# Convergence of moments

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Suppose $\left(X_{n},n\in \mathbb {N}\right)$ is a sequence of random variables taking values in $[0,1]$. Suppose that for every $k\in \mathbb {N}$,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb {E}\left(X^{k}_{n}\right)=\int x^{k}\, d\mu,
$$
for some probability measure $\mu$. Then show that $(X_{n})$ converges to $\mu$ weakly. I think this should be straightforward by the following theorem:
[image]
where $\Rightarrow$ means weak convergence or convergence in distribution. I wonder what if I have the following instead:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb {E}\left(X^{k}_{n}\right)=\frac {a}{k+a},
$$
for some $a>0$ and every $k\in \mathbb {N}$.

Comment: In what context did you find this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the measure whose density is given by $ax^{a-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$. Then $\int x^kd\mu=a/(a+k)$ for each $k\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, $(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $X_\infty$ having $ax^{a-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$ as density.